# Динамическое обновление терминала ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, терминал

Я вывожу значение постоянно обновляемой переменной в терминал в виде:

> ```
> Now value of x is value_of_x
> ```

**Как "красиво" реализовать динамический вывод этой `value_of_x` на с\с++ под терминал?**

Например, как в утилитах `top` или `lm_sensors`. Желательно свести "мерцания" и прочие неприятные вещи к минимуму. Есть куча советов как это сделать через *WinApi*, но, к сожалению, на моей *Ubuntu* его не предвидится.

Comment: под терминал линуксовский или терминал программы твоей ?

Comment: Можно использовать библиотеку **ncurses**

Comment: @SeniorAutomator под линуксовский

Answer (score 2):

Ну, вот я в виртуальной машине linux запустил такое -

```
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        printf("Value = %6d\r",i);
        fflush(stdout);
        system("sleep 1");
    }
}
```

Вполне работает. Извините за бред `system("sleep 1");` :), но не уверен, как там верно ожидание задать, linux - не моё. Главное - вывод с `'\r'` и сброс буфера.

Это, конечно, если достаточно просто в одной строке вывод. Если хотите где-то как-то красиво - это ищите соответствующую библиотеку...

Comment: Спасибо, пока сойдет, но это все равно костыль :) А system("sleep 1"); можно просто заменить на sleep(1);